# change an image of a particular button with multiple instances of the same button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, button, multiple-instances

i am making a small iOS game that has many instances of a button on the same view. the view is filled with buttons using the image of a bubble.

i need to be able to change the image of one of these buttons when it is tapped and change it back after 5 seconds however i have absolutely no idea how to do it D:

could someone suggest a possible solution please?

Comment: Are all the buttons using the same action? That is, is the same method being calling for each button when you tap on them?

Comment: yes they are all using the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your buttons are tapped, they will execute their action selector. The `sender` parameter passed to the action selector is in fact the button that was tapped and you can utilise this to change its properties. To reverse the change, you can use `dispatch_after` to delay the secondary change.

```
- (void)buttonWasTapped:(id)sender
{
    __block UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // This is the button that was tapped
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"original_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 your answer is much better, so I have deleted mine. Although I think the first setImage:forState should have UIControlStateHighlighted shouldn't it?

Comment: @bizsytes That depends on whether the action is called for `UIControlEventTouchDown` or `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. If it's `UIControlEventTouchDown`, then yes it makes more sense to use `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

Comment: i'm still quite novice, what does "_block" mean?

Comment: @JamieMcAllister The `__block` attribute makes it safe to amend the `button` variable inside a GCD block. [Here](http://nachbaur.com/blog/using-gcd-and-blocks-effectively) is a good overview of using blocks.